# Regular expression in javascript to check time with date

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to check whether the text contains a date part with it.

for ex: `mytext_12/26/2011_11:51_AM or someText_12/26/2011_13:51_PM` have a date part it returns true.

I am not too good with expressions so looking for one. the format of the date - time  part is fixed.

i got a way out for it but failing for time .

```
var containsDate = ~str.search(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/);
```

it checks the date part perfectly but when i am trying for the time part i am messing it up some where .

```
_\d{1,2}:\d{2}_(?:AM|PM) this is the part for time but i am not able to generate the final regex by combining this two.
```

Comment: in 7th grade shop class, I learned this rule: "Never use a tool that you don't know how to use."

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
.search(/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}_(AM|PM)/)
```

A good resource for regex,
  [MDN:Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: it is not working for this string which is valid " Annual_12/7/2011_3:56_PM" and for a invalid string you can check for this one "Annual_12/7/2011_234234".

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
.search(/\d+\/\d+\/\d{4}_\d+:\d+_(AM|PM)/)
```